# Python __main__.__file__

Tags: python

I have a quick question and I am having an issues locating an answer in the python docs.

File name = Test_.py

```
import __main__

def test():
    print('test text')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(__main__.__file__)
    test()
```

When I run this from a cmd line it returns:

```
c:\Python27\Test_.py
'test text'
```

But if I run it from the python by clicking  'run' ( F5 ) I get.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Test_.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(__main__.__file__)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__'
```

Why can I run this from a command line and it works fine, but if I run it from python I get an error. Is there a way to get `c:\Python27\Test_.py` when I run it from python.

Comment: How exactly are you "running" it from the interactive REPL?

Comment: It sounds like they're using IDLE?

Comment: What's with the `import __main__`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you run the script from a file then the `__main__` module is in fact that file.  In the Python interpreter prompt, on the other hand, the `__main__` module is just the default namespace the <s>interpreter</s>, specifically the interactive prompt is running in, and it has no file associated with it (loosely speaking the file is `<stdin>`).

When you hit F5 to run the code in idle it's doing the equivalent to if you just copy/pasted that code into the interpreter directly. There is no way for it to have any association with that file.

If, on the other hand, you run `import Test_` then now the code in that file is associated with the `Test_` module and you'll find that `Test_.__file__` gives the associated filename.

For what it's worth, there's almost never any reason to `import __main__`.  If you want the script to print the file it was run out of you can just have:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print __file__
```

among other possibilities.